# read from matrix cells that exist in another segment in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

lets say i have the segment in es, and the offset of the matrix address in bx (in another words => es:bx = (long int **matrix)) , how can i get the number in matrix[0][0] for example

I'm using **.model large**

i've tried doing this :

```
mov eax,dword ptr es:bx[0][0]
```

and this :

```
mov bx,dword ptr es:bx[0] 

mov eax, dword ptr es:bx[0]
```

Comment: You can't `mov` a `dword` into `bx` as the size doesn't match. Are your row pointers 16 bit near? In that case something like `mov bx, es:[bx]; mov eax, es:[bx]` could work. PS: please tag with assembler (masm?) and architecture (I added x86 for you).

Comment: the address of the matrix is in the stack , simply what i did is : mov es,[bp+10] , mov bx,[bp+8]

Comment: The instructions in your above comment are erroneous if you use 32-bit x86 assembly. Referring to `BP` is counter-productive in a 32-bit environment. Rather use `mov es, word ptr [ebp+10h] ` like specified here [8E /r ---MOV Sreg,r/m16**](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov) and `mov ebx, dword ptr [ebp+8h]` or `mov bx, word ptr [ebp+8h]`.

Comment: Is this in fact a far pointer to a far pointer of longs? (long int**matrix) or is this simply (long int *matrix) where matrix is a far pointer to long ints? If this was a function and you also showed an example of how the caller uses this and how the array is declared it would help.

Comment: You can of course load a far pointer into ES:BX with one instruction: `les bx, [bp+10]`. If this is in fact a pointer to a pointer then you'd have to dereference twice before you can access the long ints. `les bx, [bp+10]` `les bx, es:[bx]` then you could get the first long with `mov eax, es:[bx]`, the second one with `mov eax, es:[bx+4]` etc.

Comment: If this was strictly 16-bit code and had to run on an 8086 processor then EAX isn't available. You can of course do this if you know the target processor is a 386+. You'd have to have `.model large` at the top followed by `.386`. It would be important to ensure `.386` doesn't appear before `.model large`. If you had to do strictly 16-bit code you'd have to load both halves of the long int separately into two 16 bit register (ie: DX:AX).

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem

```
 mov bx,word ptr [bp+10]  ; bx = offset matrix
 mov es,word ptr [bp+12]  ; es = segment matrix
 add bx,row               ; get to the right row
 mov si,word ptr es:bx[0] ; si = offset of matrix[row]
 mov es,word ptr es:bx[2] ; es = segment of matrix[row]
 add si,col               ; to get to the right cell
 add eax,dword ptr [es:si]
```

`row` = the row number * 4
`col` = the column number * 4

Comment: I'd be curious in your function what is passed on the stack at BP+6 and BP+8 (since the matrix pointer is at BP+10)?

Comment: It’s a homework question, what’s passed on the stack at BP+6 and BP+8 is the dimensions of the matrix , if you’re curious about the question its is to sum each column in the matrix and save the results in one dimension array (it’s address passed at BP+14 and BP+16) , the code piece above tells me whats in matrix[row][col] , to sum the column i put the rows number in cx and put the above code in a loop and at the end of each iteration  I increased “row” by 4(because it’s long int) .